# Trying to make a SSH tunnel with node.js, doesnt work

Tags: node.js, database, ssh, child-process, ssh-tunnel

I have been trying for days to create a ssh tunnel in node.js but I have not been successful.

I am quite a novice so I hope you will bear with me.

I'm trying to access a database hosted in aws, the programmer who made it sent me an email with the following data to connect:

> SSH tunnel
> ssh -N -L 33306:justoaca-db-prod.ciengjumlrqb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@3.209.213.83 -i ~/.ssh/Justoaca-db-bridge.pem
>
> User DB
> justoacaread / XXXXXXXXXX
>
> pem key attached in zip with password, I send zip password separately to Javier.

the problem, is that the ssh tunnel works perfectly (being able to make a retrieve of any table of the db) as long as I make the tunnel from a vs terminal or windows command prompt.

But when I want to make it from node.js or I am left loading until it disconnects for exceeding the time limit of connection attempt, or it doesn't connect directly.

I leave below the code (there are many modules that I have been importing and trying different ways, without success).

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

class dbReadOnly {
  constructor() {
    this.dbConfig = {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 33306, // here I tried with port 22 and 3306
      user: "justoacaread",
      password: "XXXXXX",
      database: "justoaca",
    };

    this.tunnel = null;
  }

  connect(callback) {
    let sshConfig = {
      username: "ec2-user",
      host: "3.209.213.83",
      port: 33306, //tried here with 3306 and 22 too. 
      privateKey: readFileSync("./certificates/Justoaca-db-bridge.pem"),
    };

    console.log("Connecting...");
    const conn = new Client();
    conn.on('ready', () => {
      console.log("SSH connection established.");
      // Establish SSH tunnel to the remote database
      conn.forwardOut(
        // Source: Local IP and port for forwarding
        '127.0.0.1',
        33306,
        // Destination: IP and port of the remote database
        'justoaca-db-prod.ciengjumlrqb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        3306,
        (err, stream) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error establishing SSH tunnel:', err);
            callback(err);
            return;
          }

          console.log('SSH tunnel established successfully.');

          // Create a database connection using the SSH tunnel stream
          const dbConnection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 33306,
            user: 'justoacaread',
            password: 'XXXXXXXX',
            database: 'justoaca',
            stream: stream, // Pass the SSH tunnel stream as the communication channel
          });

          dbConnection.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
              callback(err);
              return;
            }

            console.log('Connected to the database successfully.');
            callback(null, dbConnection);
          });
        }
      );
    })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Error in SSH connection:', err);
        callback(err);
      })
      .connect(sshConfig);
  }

  async query(sql) {
    console.log("Executing query");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connection.query(sql, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Error executing the query:", error);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log("Resolving query results");
          resolve(results);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  async disconnect() {
    console.log("DISCONNECTING!");
    //This method was used when i tried to create the ssh with the exec command from the module child_process

    // Command to stop the SSH tunnel process
    let killCommand;
    if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
      // Windows
      killCommand = 'taskkill /IM "ssh.exe" /F';
    } else {
      // Other Unix-based systems
      killCommand = 'pkill -f "ssh -N -L 33306:justoaca-db-prod.ciengjumlrqb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"';
    }

    await exec(killCommand, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error executing the SSH disconnect command:', error);
        return;
      }

      // The command executed successfully
      console.log('SSH disconnect command executed successfully.');
      console.log('Output:', stdout);
    });

    this.connection.end();

    if (this.tunnel) {
      this.tunnel = null;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new dbReadOnly();
```

The closest I got was when I tried to use the exec method from the child_process module.
The important method, which is connect, looked like this:

```
  async connect() {
    console.log("connecting...")
    const command = 'ssh -vvv -N -L 33306:justoaca-db-prod.ciengjumlrqb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ec2-user@3.209.213.83 -i ./certificates/Justoaca-db-bridge.pem';
    await exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error executing SSH:', error);
        return;
      }
    });
   
  }
```

here is the terminal debug using the exec of the child_process on the left side, and on the right side the terminal debug using the direct command from the terminal (it works)
[image]

the strange thing about this is that sometimes it works. it retrieves the tables from node.js. but when i try again from a new terminal it breaks. sometimes it works for a while, sometimes it never works, and i don't modify the code or anything. i don't know why that could be.

so in resume, please help me to create this tunnel. I have been several days trying to fix this with no avail.

I have tried to use all the ssh modules.

When I wrap an ssh method in a promise it always breaks (stays loading until it disconnects).

Also if I don't wrap it in the promise it doesn't connect at all.

Comment: Building an app and relying on ssh tunnel to connect the db is not recommended for production and even less for development. During development you need an easy and fast way to access your db. For production you need a fast and reliable way to access your db, it should be close to the app host. The ssh tunnel should be used only if there is no other alternatives, and better be managed outside of your project code logic. I'm using ssh2 module for this, but only for simple scripts, like connecting multiple servers, running specific mysql queries, and disconnect. No long running operation.

Comment: @yeya yes I know, the thing is the programmer that made this db didnt let me to modify his page, so I need to create one from scratch but using his db as a read only user. 
But as you said, I would only need to run specific mysql queries because the idea of the app is to create reports from that db.
which ssh2 module are you using for that?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2

Comment: @yeya yeah tried that one but it doesnt work as said in the post.

Comment: 2 things to try: 1. Move to `mysql2`, the old mysql package does not support the new auth methods of mysql 8. 2. Try tun the script on WSL

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same struggle, use the "spawn" method from child_process.
That made it work.